# mariadb c api windows undefined reference to

Tags: c, api, windows-8, codeblocks, undefined-reference

I am trying to connect to mariaDB with the C API https://downloads.mariadb.org/client-native/1.0.0/
I'm on windows 8 and are using Code::Blocks 12.11 for compiling and writing the code.

- I have put the folder with .h-files in **D:\Programmering\biblotek\C\mariaDB-API\include**
- and the folder with .lib-files in **D:\Programmering\biblotek\C\mariaDB-API\lib**

So:

```
\include has all the .h files

\lib     has all the .lib files
```

**LINKING:** I have done the following to link the library:

-Linked the **\include** folder in **Settings --> Compiler.. --> Search directories --> *Compiler***

-Linked the **\lib** folder in **Settings --> Compiler.. --> Search directories --> *Linker***

-Linked **libmariadb.lib** in **Settings --> Compiler.. --> Linker Settings**

Pause...

-Linked **\include** folder in **Project --> Build Options... --> Search directories --> *Compiler***

-Linked **\lib** folder in **Project --> Build Options... --> Search directories --> *Linker***

-Linked **libmariadb.lib** in **Project --> Build Options... --> Linker Settings**

In **Project --> Build Option...** I have selected compiler **"GNU GCC Compiler"**.

Compiler flags: -g

This is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <C:\MinaProgram\Libs\sqlclientC\include\mysql.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(void) {

MYSQL mysql;
MYSQL_ROW row;
const char *aQuery = "SELECT * from livedata";

if(mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL)) { //Initiera bibliotek
fprintf(stderr, "could not initialize MySQL library\n");
exit(1);
}
printf("AH!\n");
MYSQL mysql;
mysql_init(&mysql);

if(!mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost","root","ooops","firsttest",0,NULL,0)) { //Anslut till databas, error meddelande om fel.
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect to server!\n");
}

/*GO CODE*/
if(!mysql_real_query(&mysql, aQuery, strlen(aQuery))) {
fprintf(stderr, "Query error, kinda'\n");
}

//mysql_fetch_row()

/*CLOSURE */
mysql_close(&mysql);
mysql_library_end();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile, and this is the response in Build log:

```
 ||=== test, Release ===|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x32)||undefined reference to `mysql_library_init'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x54)||undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x95)||undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0xb4)||undefined reference to `mysql_real_query@12'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0xeb)||undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0xf1)||undefined reference to `mysql_library_end'|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 3 seconds) ===|
```

I have searched stackoverflow and google and found nothing that works for me so I desided to post in detail what how I am doing wrong.

Any ideas how to connect to mariaDB with C? (How to make this porgram work)

Kind regards!

> Tip of the life time of earth: Don't get Windows 8.

Comment: This looks like a linker error. What is the build (link) command, please?

Comment: I ony use Build --> Build  (Ctrl + F9). I have not chaned anything in Code Blocks exept for linking like I posted. I dont actually know about the link command. Is it a flag or something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Link full path D:\Programmering\biblotek\C\mariaDB-API\lib\libmariadb.lib in Project --> Build Options... --> Linker Settings.

I'm not sure linker "search directories" work, I could not get them working

Alernatively, you could use CMake to generate Code::Blocks project